# Using a string in the name of an object

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to create a series of objects, but I would each like each object name to contain a string in

```
string test = "test123"
Form1 Form1Object<string goes here> = new Form1(selectedNodeText);
```

So the object name would be

```
Form1Objecttest123
```

Comment: This sounds a very unusual thing to do...could you tell us more why you need to do this?  There might be a better solution.

Comment: That won't work. Try using an appropriate data structure, such as a `List` or `Dictionary`

Comment: I do not think that this is possible. Why do you need such objects?

Comment: I have a for loop that creates a number of objects of a class (dependent on the number of hostnames I have - the class checks a hostname) At the moment all of the objects are called Form1Object, but I would rather have the hostname variable within the object name so I can distinguish between the objects easily

Comment: Mike, there might be of doing this by using emit but this is one of those questions where if you're asking it, you're doing something wrong. Consider what your code will look like and have some pity on the guy that will have to maintain it. Try to think of another way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: In that case use a dictionary (see answer below for details), or assign the name to the id property of the form and use that as your identifier.

Comment: Also, if you override ToString in Form1 and return the id property (which holds the name), then you can easily see the name of the form when debugging.

Answer (score 4):

That's impossible. You could use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Form> forms = new Dictionary<string, Form>();
forms[test] = new Form1(selectedNodeText);
```

Comment: It's totally possible. It's enormous work for absolutely no benefit, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary type would be the way to go.
Use something like

```
Dictionary<string, object> list = new Dictionary<string, object>();
list.Add("test123", new Form1(selectedNodeText));
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I then invoke this?

Comment: then you would call something like

var yourObject = list["test123"];

Comment: that would return object of type Object. if you need strongly typed object of your type then declare the dictionary<string, yourType>

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. If you had a `ModuleBuilder` object, `mb` then you could use:

```
mb.DefineType("Form1Objecttest123", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(Form1))
```

To create a type called `Form1Objecttest123` derived from `Form1`.

Then you exert enormous effort emitting any members that don't just derive from it.

This will almost certainly be of no value to you, compared to adding a name property that gets set in its constructor to `Form1` (or a *single* class derived from it) and either querying for it when you care, and/or overriding `ToString()` to return it.